# Add trend lines to some plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot2 but decided to learn it because I like its simplicity and visuals. I have a time-series (zoo) with rainfall for several cities. Looking at other questions I found out how to reshape it and plot it:

```
df <- data.frame(time = time(rain.yr),
                 city = rep(colnames(rain.yr), each = nrow(rain.yr)),
                 value = as.vector(rain.yr)) 
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value)) +
geom_line() +
facet_wrap( ~ city, ncol=4)
```

I really like the end result in terms of visuals, as it gives one plot per city but with global axes. And I found out how to add trends: `stat_smooth(method="lm")`

The problem is that I want to add trend lines to some of the plots, not all of them; just the ones where a trend is significant (I have a vector with zeros and ones for sig/non-sig).

I know how to do it with base graphics (using par and a loop to plot and only adding a line if the trend is significant) but is there a way of doing it in ggplot2?

Comment: Can't reproduce but you should be able to take a subset of your data and use it in `stat_smooth(data =...)` to only keep the ones that you want lines plotted for.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how to do this; how can I choose some cities with `data=`? If I try to do `stat_smooth(method="lm", data = "Berlin")`I get `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character`. I tried adding a column named "sigs" in the df (with zeros and ones) and do `stat_smooth(method="lm", data = df$sigs` but that just gives `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric`...

Comment: suggest to provide sample data so people here could try

Comment: @sbg you need to take a subset of your data which includes only the rows corresponding to the plots to which you need to add a line. Call it subdf then do stat_smooth(data=subdf,...)

Comment: The code in the question can be written as this: `autoplot(rain.yr)` assuming `rain.yr` is a zoo object.  See `?autoplot.zoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as been suggested, just create a dataframe of the subset you want for smoothing and use that as the data for `stat_smooth()`.

```
subdf<-diamonds[which(diamonds$clarity %in% c('SI2','SI1')),]
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=depth))+geom_point() + facet_wrap(~clarity) + geom_smooth(data=subdf)
```